Private communication between two microservices on a separate port
Inside a Kubernetes or Docker Compose cluster there are multiple microservices. These services are accessible via port 80 (without TLS) only from their internal network and they can be accessed through a gateway (in my case YARP) with TLS termination. These services need to talk to each other, and I was thinking about a scenario where they publish a separate port for their internal communications and just trust any traffic on that port. for example, they can call each other's APIs via port 8080 which is not reachable by the gateway.

So, my first question is that is this acceptable from a security point of view.
And based on the documentation, all I need to do is to add the [Host("*:8080")] for local endpoints, am I correct?
